# Cumulative pdf, integration problems.

Tags: probability, integration

Given the cumulative pdf $f(x,y)=\begin{cases}xy/96,  & \text{if 0<=x<=4 and 1<=y<=5} \\0, & \text{otherwise}  \end{cases}$

Find $P(X+Y<3)$

My attempt:

$$P(X+Y<3)=\int_{1}^{5}\int_{0}^{3-y}xy/96 dxdy=1/12$$

$$P(X+Y<3)=\int_{0}^{4}\int_{1}^{3-x}xy/96 dydx=0$$

Shouldn't those two be equal? What did I do wrong? I calculated the double integrals with this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=f5f3cbf14f4f5d6d2085bf2d0fb76e8a

Comment: Derive the marginals of $X$ and $Y$ and then derive the pdf and cdf of $Z = X+Y$ to see what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

limits are wrong

Draw a graph and see these:

$$P(X+Y<3)=\int_{0}^{2}\int_{1}^{3-x}xy/96 dydx=1/48$$ or

$$P(X+Y<3)=\int_{1}^{3}\int_{0}^{3-y}xy/96 dxdy=1/48$$